# Parskip doesn't work

Tags: paragraphs, revtex

In the following code, the comment parksip doesn't increase the spacing between paragraph and I don't understand why. How can I make a bigger spacing between my paragraph than the default one ?

```
\documentclass[aps, pra, reprint, superscriptaddress, nofootinbib]{revtex4-1}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}

\title{TITLE}


\begin{abstract}
Abstract
\end{abstract}

\maketitle
%\pacs{}

\section{Introduction}

testsdqsdsqdqsdqsdqsd qsdqsd qsd qsd qsd qsd qsdqzzadazqsx azqd qswd ZEQSDFQZ SWFUKJHQS WD QSP DKJCSDKLFG JHERJKSDFH NSLFDFJHKQSN WDFNCJKSQLDHFDNC

test DS< FSDJKHL<NF LKJSQDKFBJLKSD FNJSKD NF KJSDQ<N FQSHFKLSJDFDKQSDHFQSKJDFHSKJDFHQSD FJ

test

\end{document}
```

Some illustrations: as you can see the spacing (around red colors) is small (and doesn't vary when I change \setlength{\parskip}{1em} to \setlength{\parskip}{10em} for instance)

[image]

Comment: First of you should probably move to `revtex4-2` as `revtex4-1` is labelled `obsolete`. Additionally if you mess with parskip (you shouldn't) then perhaps move it til after `\begin{document}`

Comment: @daleif moving to revtex4-2 solved my issue. Why shouldn't I use parskip ? How should I do to proceed cleanly ?

Comment: In general increasing parskip just makes the text artificially longer and has a tendency to be added to vertical spaces where one might not want it.

Comment: @StarBucK If you use `revtex4-2` for a submission, you should stick to *their* rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As daleif said in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/585414/parskip-doesnt-work/585418#comment1471318_585414) redefining `\parskip` is a dangerous endeavour, as this vertical space might pop out when you don't expect it. (Plus, journals can be cranky when you change their templates...)

This being said, I'd like to explain why your code does not work with `revtex4-1` but it does with `revtex4-2`.

Most differences between the two files are cosmetic, but `revtex4-2` has one important addition: at the end of the class it issues `\normalsize`. This means that in the preamble the font is set and `1em` has its particular value.

With `revtex4-1` the `\normalsize` is called only at `\begin{document}`. The current font in the preamble is still `\nullfont`, and `1em` of `\nullfont` is the same as zero.

If you want to redefine `\parskip` with `revtex4-1`, you have to do it *after* `\begin{document}`. In the preamble you can still set `\parskip` by using "hard" lengths (`pt`, `mm`, ...) instead of font-related ones (`em`, `ex`) (but I wouldn't recommend it).